# Iteration at the end of the end of pages returns false

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests

I have methods in the test that work correctly, but when the pages end it returns false. How do I make sure that after the method is running, true is returned?

I know that I need to fix the logic in the initNextPageButton method but I don't understand how

```
public List<String> collectResultsFromPage() {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='_8v6CF']")));
        List<WebElement> resultsNameWebElement = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//article//h3[@data-zone-name = 'title']//span"));
        return resultsNameWebElement.stream()
                .map(WebElement::getText)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

private boolean initNextPageButton() {
    try {
        goNextPageButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@class, '_3OFYT')]"));
        return true;
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        return false;
    }
}

public void collectResults() {
    findResults = collectResultsFromPage();
    while (initNextPageButton()) {
        goNextPageButton.click();
        findResults.addAll(collectResultsFromPage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there are multiple ways to do this, here I would do it using `findElements`(plural) to check the list size, if it contains more than zero element then go ahead, return true or else return false.

```
private boolean initNextPageButton() {
        List<WebElement> goNextPageButton = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[contains(@class, '_3OFYT')]"));
        if(goNextPageButton.size() > 0){
           goNextPageButton.get(0).click();
           return true;
         }
        else
           return false;
}
```

Comment: then it is not possible to click on the button in the following method

Comment: No it's possible in case you wanna click using this method goNextPageButton.get(0). click (); should do the job

Comment: Cannot resolve symbol 'goNextPageButton' and the test crashes when trying to go to the next page

Comment: @OttoRahn : hmm.. I am not sure which code you've tried, anyway I have updated above

Comment: I understand thank you